# Increasing depth buffer precision far from the camera

Tags: c++, opengl

I have a project I'm working on that is making movies from a simulation. The simulation is passed from another program that defines the projection matrix.

The issue I am running into is that the other program has a sort of 'fake' orthographic view, what I mean by this is that its projection matrix is as follows:

```
PerspectiveMatrix = glm::perspective(3.5, 1, 1.0f, 50.0f);
```

And it uses the LookAt function:

```
ViewMatrix = glm::lookAt(
    (2000,-3000,2000), // eye 
    (0,0,0), // center 
    (0,0,1)//up 
);
```

So what I mean by 'fake' orthographic view is that they have positioned the camera far enough away (and small angle to zoom the scene) that the "view lines" (for lack of a better term) are almost parallel like in a real orthographic projection.

So this is all fine and well but what I've run into, and is an issue in the other program as well, is that all of the high precision depth testing is close to the camera and in my case this is empty space. This means that there is quite a lot of z fighting as shown in the link below:

[image: Screenshot]

So my question is what ways can I change my depth testing in order to maybe bias the buffer towards the far plane? or something along those lines. I have tried moving the NearPlane farther out, which has the result of zooming out the screen, so I compensate with a narrower angle in the perspective. But doing this enough times makes the problem worse, there isn't z fighting but it doesn't draw things at the right depth. The spheres end up on top of everything.

I did find some info at Outerra:
http://outerra.blogspot.com/2012/11/maximizing-depth-buffer-range-and.html
They had some ideas for reversing the depth buffer but it was Nvidia specific and I need to be compatible with both ATI and Nvidia

Comment: Why not move the camera closer and use a real orthographic projection?

Comment: It would certainly sole the depth issue, the problem is that my program needs to look exactly the same as the 'parent' program. They are both showing the same images, but mine is writing those to an AVI versus just previewing the scene. Essentially the user previews the screen to make sure they got the right result and then they call my program to make it into a movie

Comment: One way is to make the texture that you are drawing on larger. The larger it is, the more accurate your result will be but it will increase

Comment: There is nothing NV-specific about flipping the depth-range, by the way. In fact you will find that the most vocal advocate for it, Emil Perrson, worked for AMD for a few years. If you invert the depth buffer and use a floating-point representation you can achieve really good results.

Comment: Are you using the programmable or the fixed pipeline?

Comment: Tommy - Using the programmable pipeline
Andon - Didn't notice the comment that AMD added that functionality, but am I correct that you need at least opengl 4.2 to use `glDepthRangedNV ` in order to flip the depth range?

Comment: it's not really answer. You can do multiple pass with different projection matrix and then combine the results. read more about depth precision http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/depthbuffer.htm. I just had the similar task couple days ago https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23157360/precision-for-depth-buffer-on-ipad-3-4-and-ipad-air

Comment: @user3565590: If you write `@` before the username in a comment, it will notify them automatically. I could have gone days without seeing that comment ;) As for your question, it really comes down to the behavior of the depth range part of viewport mapping in GL. Traditionally, values are clamped to [0,1] even when you use a floating-point depth buffer. `glDepthRangedNV` gets around this, but you really do not even need that - you can invert the near/far plane in your projection matrix and adjust the depth test/clear value accordingly.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman useful feature haha, when you say invert near/far plane do you mean that when I call the projection matrix I would enter in 1/nearPlane and 1/far plane? And sorry, what do you mean by the depth test/clear value?

Comment: @user3565590: I should have been more clear. By invert, what I really meant was to swap the parameters. So that you pass near for far and far for near. But, when you do this, you also need to swap the direction of the depth test (e.g. `GL_LESS` becomes `GL_GREATER`) and you should also change the value that you clear your depth buffer to (usually **1.0**, now it would need to be **0.0**).

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Ahh, ok, I see what you mean by invert. So I've changed the perspective to `glm::perspective(InitalZoom + SceneZoom, Aspect, 50.0f, 0.6f);` and added `glDepthFunc(GL_GREATER);` and after `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);` added `glClearDepth(0.0);` So this caused my textures on my HUD to render but otherwise the screen is still blank

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I am doing back face culling, I disabled it (assuming that it would at least draw if that was the issue) but it still draws just the HUD parts. Would it be possible that the scene has 'moved' so I need to adjust camera position again?

Comment: I just took a look at some code I have for doing something similar, and I noticed that instead of swapping the clip planes in the projection matrix, I actually just call `glDepthRange (1.0f, 0.0f)`. You might consider trying that with the other changes I described.

Comment: This will only do something useful for you if you are using a floating-point depth buffer, I should point out. That often means drawing into an FBO since you cannot easily get a default framebuffer with an FP depth buffer (this requires an extension such as `WGL_EXT_depth_float`, which frameworks may not expose).

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Thanks! that did the trick it's still not perfect but it made a big difference. `glDepthRange` minus the switch of near and far on a FBO was the solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both logarithmic depth and reversed depth mapping described in that [blog post](http://outerra.blogspot.com/2012/11/maximizing-depth-buffer-range-and.html) will work for you.

Reverse floating point is better, and it works normally in DirectX. In OpenGL it won't bring you any extra precision due to a design flaw, unless the driver exposes the [NV_depth_buffer_float](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/NV/depth_buffer_float.txt) extension, through which you can effectively turn off the bias that makes it unusable normally.

AMD supports that extension since their 13.12 Catalyst drivers, so the technique is usable on all 5000+ series AMD GPUs (older series aren't supported by the drivers).

Answer (score 3):

Simpler than any of above: move your znear further from the camera. Looks like it's the third parameter of glm::perspective(), set to 1.0 in your example. Set it as large as you can before it starts clipping away stuff in the foreground of your scene, and your z-buffer precision problems will probably go away.

Reverse-float-z is great but only really needed for scenes with wider field of view and deeper geometry. For a near-orthographic scene like yours, just set your znear/zfar appropriately.